# Examples of LLVM X86 backend passes modifying MachineBasicBlocks?

Tags: c++, llvm, backend, llvm-c++-api

I've used the LLVM IR API for some time now and is pretty comfortable using it.

However, when it comes to the x86 backend I'm lost...

First of all, I cannot find a reference on how to create new instructions and insert them into a `MachineBasicBlock`.

Next, the Backend API doesn't mirror the familiar IR API, where I can create new IR instructions using `new` and insert them before other instructions or at the end of a basic block.

Finally, using CLion, when opening the project, the `.inc` files are not found in the source directory, so a lot of references are not resolved, e.g., register info.

Could someone link to a ressource on how to program with the backend LLVM API?

Also, an example of how to add a few instructions (e.g., `mov` or `lea`) into a `MachineBasicBlock` would also be welcome!